# how many spanning graphs are formed by the given number of vertices and edges?

Tags: graph-theory

If a graph has $n_1$ vertices and $n_2$ edges then how many spanning graphs  are there formed by them?

Spanning graph -A subgraph  H of a graph G  is said to be spanning subgraph if all the vertices of G are  present in the subgraph  H.

Answer (score 2):

Since each edge may or may not belong to a spanning subgraph, the answer is $2^{n_2}$.